# finding all possible routes. Is it a travelling salesman problem?

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms

I'm not very clever on mathematics and I'm not being able to start building a solution to this. I'm trying to develop an algorithm with which I can solve the following problem.
Let's say I have a set of number $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$, I want to go from $x$ ($x$ being in the subset $\{1,2,3\}$) to $4$ using all possible routes given that the possible routes are:

starting from $1$
$$
\{1,4\}, \{(1,2),(2,4)\},\{(1,3),(3,4)\},\{(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)\}  
$$
starting from $2$
$$
\{2,4\}, \{(2,3),(3,4)\}  
$$
starting from $3$
$$
\{3,4\}  
$$

As I said I'm not being able to develop a proper solution without doing it by hand, I would like to build an algorithm in which the input would be the boundaries of the set (in the case I presented $1$ and $4$) and the output would be the subsets with all possible combinations. Where can I start? Is this traveling salesman problem? What literature could I use to find out about this problem?

Comment: The fact that your possible routes all respect the order in the set of numbers suggests that this is a tractable problem, not like the traveling salesman. I think that there are straightforward algorithms (nested loops, or recursion) that you can write in pseudocode and translate into any programming language. Just begin with what you do systematically by hand.

Comment: I see from your profile that you're familiar with Python. This is easy to do, using the powerset recipe in the [itertools docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes). [Here's a brief example](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxNj0FqxDAMRfc-xYdubMYUposuCr1F98WZKI3AsQZJs-jtaydpqcAbP3__p0VlAzupi1QDb3dRx20t3DJusk3cirM0C2GmBSoPJ4tVMlZObwF9DO_Q0r6oX-OC6452slKZM7xw7U9GKGXElfNB7TEZ-Ujvdc9LV_kcKmWqFP93R8vQI4RFFApuv5XUoqXLNR14UB_0_PwwHPPNVOfdqDv6OF0rhCd8kHn4y50LvmS8nuvdlZtHTz-HWloB&lang=python)

Comment: @PM2Ring wow! that was really helpful! I need to elaborate a more general example but the pythonic way is a very good way to start! thanks!

Comment: No worries. My code assumes the numbers in a route must always increase, since that seems to be the case from your example. Pock Suppet's answer doesn't assume that. If there *are* restrictions on the subpaths, that's not too hard to handle by filtering out illegal combinations from the solutions. But if there are lots of restrictions it becomes more efficient to enforce them while building the routes, rather than filtering them out at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand your question, I think you missed e.g. $1\to3\to2\to4$.

You are using here **permutation groups** of the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and that would be a good thing to search for in the literature.  These are subgroups of the **symmetric group**.

Note that this is often not always a commutative or abelian group because it matters in which orders you permute elements.

The **transpositions** are the elements of the permutation group that exchange two elements and leave all the others fixed.  E.g. $(1,2)$ is the transposition that exchanges $1$ for $2$.  You are constructing a chain of transpositions that exchanges $4$ with any element in $\{1,2,3\}$

A simple algorithm for your purposes begins with the observation that there will never be more than three steps (assuming you do not want to retrace your steps.
If you did, there would be infinitely many solutions).  Knowing this you can construct an exhaustive list of every chain of transpositions of length three.  Then you can check each in turn to determine whether it satisfies your required conditions.

All your examples are increasing, but you don't give this as a rule.  If you require your sequences to be increasing then you can just use this rule to filter out appropriate solutions.

Comment: That's precisely what I needed! I will use this a way of starting! thank you very much!